# Menu hover displacement in IE9 - CSS

Tags: css, menu, hover, internet-explorer-9

I have a problem with hover on this site I'm doing. The menu is ok in all pages, except the home. What is kinda awkward, 'cause I'm just using php include to change the content, and the header, menu and footer are always the same.

In Firefox and Chrome it's ok, but the problem is that when I mouseover the menu on IE9 it has a displacement, like the image:

example
[image: example]
http://i74.photobucket.com/albums/i265/_k_ps_/exemplo.gif

I think it's something with the display: block, but I don't know how to fix it and make the menu work properly :(

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div id="menu" class="group">
    <ul>
    <li id="menu-01"><a href="indexteste.php?page=home" title="Página Inicial"><span>Home</span></a></li>

    <li id="menu-02"><a href="indexteste.php?page=empresa" title="Conheça a PROEL"><span>A Empresa</span></a></li>

    <li id="menu-03"><a href="galeria_representacao.php?image=0">
    <img src="images/representacao.jpg" class="menu-head" onMouseOver="this.src='images/representacao-hover.jpg'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/representacao.jpg'"></a>  
            <ul class="menu-body">
                    <li><a href="indexteste.php?page=home">Teste1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="galeria_representacao.php?image=0">Teste2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Teste3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Teste4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Teste5</a></li>   
            </ul>
    </li> 

    <li id="menu-04"><a href="indexteste.php?page=servicos" title="Serviços"> <span>Serviços</span></a></li>

    <li id="menu-05"><a href="indexteste.php?page=projetos" title="Projetos"><span>Projetos</span></a></li>

    <li id="menu-06"><a href="indexteste.php?page=novidades" title="Notícias e Novidades"><span>Novidades</span></a></li>

    <li id="menu-07"><a href="indexteste.php?page=contato" title="Entre em contato"><span>Contato</span></a></li>                           

    <li id="menu-08"><a href="#" title="E-mail"><span>E-mail</span></a></li>

    <li id="menu-09"><a href="#" title="Login"><span>Login</span></a></li>

    </ul>

    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#menu {
    width: 834px;
    height: 44px;
    background-image: url(../images/menu-up.jpg);
    display: block;
}

#menu ul {
    width: 834px;
    height: 44px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

#menu ul span {
    display: none;
}

#menu ul li {   
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#menu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 12;
}

#menu li ul li {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #0676c4;
    width: 157px;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#menu li ul li a {
    clear: both;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}

#menu li ul li a:hover {        
    background-color: #87c5f1;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0;      
} 

#menu ul li, #menu ul a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 44px;
    display: block;
}

#menu-01 {
    left: 0px;
    width: 75px;
}

#menu-01 a:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/menu-down.png);
}

#menu-02 {
    left: 0px;
    width: 112px;
}

#menu-02 a:hover {
    background: url(../images/menu-down.png) -75px;
}

#menu-03 {
    background-image: url(../images/representacao.jpg);
    left: 0px;
    width: 157px;
    z-index: 11;
    border: 0;
}

#menu-04 {
    left: 0px; 
    width: 103px;
}

#menu-04 a:hover {
    background: url(../images/menu-down.png) -344px;
}

#menu-05 {
    left: 0px;
    width: 108px;
}

#menu-05 a:hover {
    background: url(../images/menu-down.png) -447px;
}

#menu-06 {
    left: 0px;
    width: 113px;
}

#menu-06 a:hover {
    background: url(../images/menu-down.png) -555px;
}

#menu-07 {      
    left: 0px;
    width: 101px;
}

#menu-07 a:hover {
    background: url(../images/menu-down.png) -668px;
}

.menu-head {
    border-width: 0;
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I put your code (and modified it a bit) in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qk5jm/).

The problem, from what I see, seems to be with the 3rd element, which has a child `ul`.

From what I see from there, you have a problem with your CSS :

This CSS style

```
#menu ul {
    width: 834px;
    height: 44px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Affect this HTML element :

```
<ul class="menu-body">
```

Which you probably don't want to. ([fixed here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qk5jm/1/))

But I'm not sure it's your error, the code you supplied needs the images, and I do not have them...

Also, all your `left:0px` are useless.

If you want a better answer, you'll have to enhance your question (and/or the jsfiddle!). **:-)**

Comment: thanks, Kraz :)
but I was looking for a solution in other posts/sites and found that it can be a mysterious bug of IE9 that creates this 1px shifting.
I put this on the code:
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
and now it works properly.

Comment: well, actually it worked once, but now seem like the emulate doesn't work anymore. bizarre. I'll keep trying.

Comment: update: the emulation works now. I just modified the tag: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7, IE=9" /> It's not perfect but the displacement is reduced.

Comment: That's a way to tell IE to use a different rendering engine. Your problem still exist in other IE version, but maybe you do not care. Glad you found something.